# How do I access a value from within this hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access the `lat` and `lon` values within this hash, but when I call `@object["lat"]` or `object[:lat]` it returns `nil`. Here is the hash:

```
{"searchresults"=>{"place"=>{"place_id"=>"100066", "osm_type"=>"node", "osm_id"=>"107775", "place_rank"=>"15", "boundingbox"=>"51.3473219,51.6673219,-0.2876474,0.0323526", "lat"=>"51.5073219", "lon"=>"-0.1276474", "display_name"=>"London, Greater London, England, SW1A 2DX, United Kingdom", "class"=>"place", "type"=>"city", "importance"=>"0.9654895765402", "icon"=>"https://locationiq.org/static/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png"}, "timestamp"=>"Thu, 25 Apr 19 01:43:32 +0530", "attribution"=>"https://locationiq.com/attribution", "querystring"=>"london", "polygon"=>"false", "exclude_place_ids"=>"100066", "more_url"=>"https://locationiq.org/static/search.php?q=london&exclude_place_ids=100066&format=xml"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have:

```
object = {"searchresults"=>{"place"=>{"place_id"=>"100066", "osm_type"=>"node", "osm_id"=>"107775", "place_rank"=>"15", "boundingbox"=>"51.3473219,51.6673219,-0.2876474,0.0323526", "lat"=>"51.5073219", "lon"=>"-0.1276474", "display_name"=>"London, Greater London, England, SW1A 2DX, United Kingdom", "class"=>"place", "type"=>"city", "importance"=>"0.9654895765402", "icon"=>"https://locationiq.org/static/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png"}, "timestamp"=>"Thu, 25 Apr 19 01:43:32 +0530", "attribution"=>"https://locationiq.com/attribution", "querystring"=>"london", "polygon"=>"false", "exclude_place_ids"=>"100066", "more_url"=>"https://locationiq.org/static/search.php?q=london&exclude_place_ids=100066&format=xml"}}
```

You might want to use:

```
object.dig('searchresults','place','lat')
 => "51.5073219"
```

The benefit is that, if by chance, your `object` doesn't have the expected structure, you'll receive a `nil`:

```
object.dig('searchresults','foo_place','lat')
 => nil
```

Whereas the sequential hash accessors will throw an error:

```
object['searchresults']['foo_place']['lat']
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):60
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

And it's probably easier to deal with a `nil` than a `NoMethodError`.

If you prefer to use symbols as your keys (instead of strings), then you could do:

```
object.with_indifferent_access.dig(:searchresults, :place, :lat)
 => "51.5073219"
```

Note that, without `with_indifferent_access` (or one of the other means of converting your keys from strings to symbols):

```
object[:searchresults][:place][:lat]
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):67
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@object["searchresults"]["place"]["lat"]
```

Comment: Thanks! that works. Why does it not act like a normal hash? Is it an embedded hash?

Comment: It is a normal hash with normal hashes inside of it. This is how you navigate through the levels.

Comment: It works like normal Hash, but you didn't take your "lat" data, because of this "lat" data inside "place" hash, and "place" hash inside "searchresults"

@object[:searchresults][:place][:lat] also, should work!

Answer (score 1):

If you have this code you can retrieve `lat` and `lon` this way :

```
object = {"searchresults"=>{"place"=>{"place_id"=>"100066", "osm_type"=>"node", "osm_id"=>"107775", "place_rank"=>"15", "boundingbox"=>"51.3473219,51.6673219,-0.2876474,0.0323526", "lat"=>"51.5073219", "lon"=>"-0.1276474", "display_name"=>"London, Greater London, England, SW1A 2DX, United Kingdom", "class"=>"place", "type"=>"city", "importance"=>"0.9654895765402", "icon"=>"https://locationiq.org/static/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png"}, "timestamp"=>"Thu, 25 Apr 19 01:43:32 +0530", "attribution"=>"https://locationiq.com/attribution", "querystring"=>"london", "polygon"=>"false", "exclude_place_ids"=>"100066", "more_url"=>"https://locationiq.org/static/search.php?q=london&exclude_place_ids=100066&format=xml"}}
lat = object["searchresults"]["place"]["lat"]
lon = object["searchresults"]["place"]["lon"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to see the hash structure once it's properly indented. So here's the structure for the hash you want to access:

```rb
{
  "searchresults"=> {
    "place"=> {
      "place_id"=>"100066", 
      "osm_type"=>"node", 
      "osm_id"=>"107775", 
      "place_rank"=>"15", 
      "boundingbox"=>"51.3473219,51.6673219,-0.2876474,0.0323526", 
      "lat"=>"51.5073219", 
      "lon"=>"-0.1276474", 
      "display_name"=>"London, Greater London, England, SW1A 2DX, United Kingdom", 
      "class"=>"place", "type"=>"city", "importance"=>"0.9654895765402", 
      "icon"=>"https://locationiq.org/static/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png"
    }, 
    "timestamp"=>"Thu, 25 Apr 19 01:43:32 +0530", "attribution"=>"https://locationiq.com/attribution", 
    "querystring"=>"london", "polygon"=>"false", "exclude_place_ids"=>"100066", 
    "more_url"=>"https://locationiq.org/static/search.php?q=london&exclude_place_ids=100066&format=xml"
  }
}
```

From here, you can see that the `lat` key is actually under the `searchresults -> place -> lat` path. Therefore, you could reach it with

```rb
@object['searchresults']['place']['lat']
```

or alternatively

```rb
@object.dig('searchresults', 'place', 'lat')
```